# Find the records if all words exists in given text

Tags: c#, sql-server

We think elastic search is right tool for text search but would like to confirm if this is possible in SQL Server. I will try to explain the problem. We have a `search` column that contains words separated with `;`, *e.g.* `apple;ball boom;cat;doll;egg`.

```
search
---------------------------
ab;ac;sing sing;tommy paul; -> record 1
paul john;oh oh;taxi;no no; -> record 2
taxi;oh oh;ring;npm nodejs; -> record 3
```

We would like to query records that matches all the words but the words does not need to be in the order.

- `search.find("ab;oh oh;")`. Here `ab` is in record 1 and `oh oh` is in record 2, so the query should return empty set.
- For `search.find("taxi; oh oh;")` it should return records 2 and 3.
- For `search.find("oh oh;sam")` it should return empty set.

We are expecting if this is possible using inbuilt queries in SQL Server and are they fast enough. Assuming we won't have more than 10k records. We are comfortable with C# solution too (Regex is preferable than LINQ which ends up loops assuming string of arrays). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you normalize the data in the DB so you have a table of record ids and all the individual search terms?  Then you can do the searching with SQL.

Comment: @juharr We have lot of criteria, going with normalization requires lots of joins. I think joins are not good at text searching I believe. The words can range upto 1k. We dont think sql server can scale with joins. Let me know if we are wrong

Comment: With what you have you're going to end up having to inspect every single record and if you do that with in memory code that's way worse than joins in a DB.

Comment: I agree we are not looking for c# in-memory code, however 10k records with 4gb RAM should be fair enough in C# but we are looking for speed. We are comfortable with SQL, C# or elastic search tool. If we scale to 100k records than definately elastic search is something we need to look at. rather than jumping to c# we are looking if there is something we can quickly reuse in sqlserver

Comment: Even a pure SQL solution is just going to be using `like` which will require table scans and will not be able to take advantage of indexing.  If the data is normalized then you'll be able to index it and take advantage of that.

Comment: Are you using Entity or SQL client?  I assume you are using entity.  If line is the input then use something like this : "ab;oh oh;".Split(new char[] { ';' }).All(x => line.Contains(x));

Answer (score 1):

For your example, SQL would be

```
  select * 
  from table 
  where ';' + search like '%;ab;%'
  and ';' + search like '%;oh oh;%'
```

Would would need function which takes search workd ("ab;oh oh;"), split it into individual words (["ab", "oh, oh"]) and create SQL (depends on what language/framework is used for DB assess, if it's T-SQL then create sql and run it create via sp_executesql)

Comment: interesting but I see we end up with dynamic sql query generation and also if we have 5 words than it had to do linear like 5 times full text search on the same text. If text is too long. I think this will be slow. let me know if i am wrong

Comment: I wouldn't worry about number of words to search (scan string loaded in memory 5 times is not a problem), the main problem is that LIKE cannot use indexes so search time will increase proportionally to number of records in the table. It would be better to have separate table with search words (one-to-many reltionship).